# “su: must be run from a terminal” with lxc

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I am trying to understand the following error and the solution

I connect to the lxc container with the following command

```
#lxc exec cont-01 -- sudo --login --user ubuntu
```

and after login in on the terminal when i execute a command to switch users

```
#su -l bob
```

I get the following error:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

The following provides a solution [“Must be connected to a terminal error” with screen -x command on a Linux Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471261/must-be-connected-to-a-terminal-error-with-screen-x-command-on-a-linux-contai)
 which is to execute the following:

```
#script /dev/null
```

I was wondering if someone could explain what the issue is and why executing that command solves the problem.